# Retrieve data from SQL Server 2005 with SQL Server 2008 SSIS Data Flow via procedure with parameter in data source

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, ssis

I was trying to retrieve data from a procedure on SQL Server 2005 and populate a table on SQL Server 2008. Packet is on SQL Server 2008. I have a SQL Task which I use to get the date. The result set is set to a variable called `MeasurementPeriodid`, an int32 data type. In my data flow in an OLEDB source I have the SQL command: `exec [dbo].[MIS_usp_Core_Fill_Arranegement] ?`. On the Parameters tab, `@MSR_PRD_ID` is mapped to `User::MeasurementPeriodid`.

The procedure accepts MSR_PRD_ID INT. In the procedure the result set is returned from table variable. Columns in this table, which correspond to columns in destination (and which is date data type), are a datetime data type.

When I tried to preview I get this error:

> Error at Arrangement [OLE DB Source [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cieIy.png)]: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:
>   0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL
>   Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description:
>   "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.".
>
> Error at Arrangement [OLE DB Source [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cieIy.png)]: Unable to retrieve column
>   information from the data source. Make sure your target table in the
>   database is available.

(Microsoft Visual Studio)

When I execute the procedure from SSMS it works fine. I tried to comment out datetime columns in the query which returns a result set from table variable in the procedure, but the error is the same.

[image]

Procedure (not all, just begining and end):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MIS_usp_Core_Fill_Arranegement] 
@MSR_PRD_ID INT
AS
/**
TestSQL:
EXEC [dbo].[MIS_usp_Core_Fill_Arranegement] @MSR_PRD_ID = 20160831

**/
BEGIN
DECLARE @lclval nvarchar(20),       
    @datum varchar(15),
    @imalacid int

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET FMTONLY OFF;

DECLARE  @Arrangement  TABLE
(
    [MeasurementPeriodId] datetime,
    [ArrangementId] bigint,
    [ArrangementUniqueId] nvarchar(100),
    [CustomerId] bigint,
    [CustomerUniqueId] nvarchar(100),
    [ArrangementProductId] int, -- MAPIRANJE
    [OrganizationUnitId] bigint,
    [OrganizationUnitUniqueId] [nvarchar](100),
    [NonPerformingLoanFlag] bit,
    [ActivationDate] datetime,
    [ArrangementTypeUniqueId] nvarchar(100),
    [LastRenewalDate] datetime,
    [NumberOfIssues] int, -- BROJ IZDATIH KARTICA
    [ExpirationDate] datetime, -- EST_END_DT
    [CancelationDate] datetime, -- END_DT
    [CurrencyId] int,
    [CurrencyTypeId] int,
    [TermTypeId] int
)

select --[MeasurementPeriodId],
    [ArrangementId],
    [ArrangementUniqueId],
    [CustomerId],
    [CustomerUniqueId],
    [ArrangementProductId], -- MAPIRANJE
    [OrganizationUnitId],
    [OrganizationUnitUniqueId],
    [NonPerformingLoanFlag],
    --[ActivationDate],
    [ArrangementTypeUniqueId],
    --[LastRenewalDate],
    [NumberOfIssues], -- BROJ IZDATIH KARTICA
    --[ExpirationDate], -- EST_END_DT
    --[CancelationDate], -- END_DT
    [CurrencyId],
    [CurrencyTypeId],
    [TermTypeId]
from @Arrangement
```

Comment: In the variables window, does the variable `User::MeasurementPeriodid` have a non-zero value?  What happens if you hardcode that value into you exec statement and preview?  `exec [dbo].[MIS_usp_Core_Fill_Arrangement] 20160813` Does the preview work then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify your stored procedure to add the following no-op right after the `BEGIN`, does SSIS play nicely with the stored procedure?

```
IF (NULL = NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        CAST(NULL AS datetime) AS [MeasurementPeriodId]
    ,   CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [ArrangementId]
    ,   CAST(NULL AS nvarchar(100)) AS [ArrangementUniqueId]
    ,   CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [CustomerId]
    ,   CAST(NULL AS nvarchar(100)) AS [CustomerUniqueId]
    ,   CAST(NULL AS int) AS [ArrangementProductId] 
    ,   CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS [OrganizationUnitId]
    ,   CAST(NULL AS [nvarchar](100)) AS [OrganizationUnitUniqueId]
    ,   CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [NonPerformingLoanFlag]
    ,   CAST(NULL AS datetime) AS [ActivationDate]
    ,   CAST(NULL AS nvarchar(100)) AS [ArrangementTypeUniqueId]
    ,   CAST(NULL AS datetime) AS [LastRenewalDate]
    ,   CAST(NULL AS int) AS [NumberOfIssues] 
    ,   CAST(NULL AS datetime) AS [ExpirationDate]
    ,   CAST(NULL AS datetime) AS [CancelationDate]
    ,   CAST(NULL AS int) AS [CurrencyId]
    ,   CAST(NULL AS int) AS [CurrencyTypeId]
    ,   CAST(NULL AS int) AS [TermTypeId];
END
```

If so, the root issue is that SSIS is having trouble determining the structure of the output table because it's a temporary object. The above hack is the 2005/2008 way of providing a hint to the SSIS engine what the metadata will look like.

Comment: Yes, that was a problem. This work fine now. BR billinkc